# How to create tag for subtechnologies

Tags: discussion, tags

I am in the process on cleaning up the XMPP question space for XMPP to make it easier to find relevant and up to date information.

I see that there is subtag for large subset of the protocol, that are a whole topic on their own. For example, I found the tag [muc] and [multiuserchat].

This is clearly a duplicate and could make great synonyms, however I would like to get your opinion of what would be good tag name for that case.

'muc' is not really self explanatory outside XMPP world. 'multiuserchat' is a bit generic.
Other tags that could be possible are linking the technologies together like: 'xmpp-muc' or 'muc-xmpp'.

What is the best approach for those type of subtechnology tags ?

Comment: Why not have it tagged both [xmpp] and [multiuserchat]?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. My question was because I was afraid to pollute the multiuserchat tags as people may want to use multi user chat with other technologies. But you are right this is true they could filter by combining with another tag or search for "not xmpp"